# double free or corruption (out) fclose

Tags: c, glibc

```
*** glibc detected *** /home/ghoshs/workspace/Simulator/Debug/Simulator: double free or corruption (out): 0x00000000017e6030 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x7e626)[0x7f34b8553626]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(fclose+0x155)[0x7f34b85432a5]
/home/ghoshs/workspace/Simulator/Debug/Simulator[0x40e7bf]
/home/ghoshs/workspace/Simulator/Debug/Simulator[0x40e94a]
/home/ghoshs/workspace/Simulator/Debug/Simulator[0x40e357]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xed)[0x7f34b84f676d]
/home/ghoshs/workspace/Simulator/Debug/Simulator[0x405e19]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-0128c000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 1576650                            /home/ghoshs/workspace/Simulator/Debug/Simulator
0148b000-0148c000 r-xp 00e8b000 08:06 1576650                            /home/ghoshs/workspace/Simulator/Debug/Simulator
0148c000-014bd000 rwxp 00e8c000 08:06 1576650                            /home/ghoshs/workspace/Simulator/Debug/Simulator
014bd000-014c7000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
017e6000-01807000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7f34b84d5000-7f34b8688000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 4849816                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7f34b8688000-7f34b8887000 ---p 001b3000 08:06 4849816                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7f34b8887000-7f34b888b000 r-xp 001b2000 08:06 4849816                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7f34b888b000-7f34b888d000 rwxp 001b6000 08:06 4849816                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7f34b888d000-7f34b8892000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7f34b8892000-7f34b88a7000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 4853364                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f34b88a7000-7f34b8aa6000 ---p 00015000 08:06 4853364                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f34b8aa6000-7f34b8aa7000 r-xp 00014000 08:06 4853364                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f34b8aa7000-7f34b8aa8000 rwxp 00015000 08:06 4853364                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f34b8aa8000-7f34b8ac0000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 4855760                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.15.so
7f34b8ac0000-7f34b8cbf000 ---p 00018000 08:06 4855760                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.15.so
7f34b8cbf000-7f34b8cc0000 r-xp 00017000 08:06 4855760                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.15.so
7f34b8cc0000-7f34b8cc1000 rwxp 00018000 08:06 4855760                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.15.so
7f34b8cc1000-7f34b8cc5000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7f34b8cc5000-7f34b8dbe000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 4849815                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.15.so
7f34b8dbe000-7f34b8fbd000 ---p 000f9000 08:06 4849815                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.15.so
7f34b8fbd000-7f34b8fbe000 r-xp 000f8000 08:06 4849815                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.15.so
7f34b8fbe000-7f34b8fbf000 rwxp 000f9000 08:06 4849815                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.15.so
7f34b8fbf000-7f34b8fe1000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 4849818                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
7f34b91bd000-7f34b91c1000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7f34b91dd000-7f34b91e1000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7f34b91e1000-7f34b91e2000 r-xp 00022000 08:06 4849818                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
7f34b91e2000-7f34b91e4000 rwxp 00023000 08:06 4849818                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
7fffc3f01000-7fffc3fab000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7fffc3fff000-7fffc4000000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
```

I am doing a simple 
`FILE* temp_dataset = fopen(dataset_filnames,"w");`
and after few write operations i am closing it using a simple
`fclose(temp_dataset);`
At this point I am getting the double free corruption error. In the function I am just generating two random numbers that will act as a source and a destination, which will be further used by algorithm to find routes on a graph. But that part is totally independent of this part of the code. (Sorry for the irrelevant info stack overflow would not let me post the question.)

```
void generate_dataset(int number_of_src_dest,
        char dataset_filnames[],NI* network_info, int k, int network_set,int dataset_num)
{
    int i,j;

    printf("Generating Dataset for the Network Set...\n");
    sprintf(dataset_filnames,"src_dest_pair_#nodes_%d_#SDP_%d_NS_%d_DS_%d",NUMBER_OF_NODES,number_of_src_dest,network_set,dataset_num);
    printf("in file.. %s\n",dataset_filnames);
    int temp_topo[NUMBER_OF_NODES][NUMBER_OF_NODES];
    copy_2D_array(NUMBER_OF_NODES,NUMBER_OF_NODES,temp_topo,network_info->topology);
    FILE* temp_dataset = fopen(dataset_filnames,"w");
    int number_of_source_destination_generated = 0;
    int source_destination[_BIG_SIZE][2];
    for (i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_NODES; ++i)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < NUMBER_OF_NODES; ++j)
        {

            if(i != j)
            {
                int shortestpath[NUMBER_OF_NODES];
                int dist = shortest_path(i,j,temp_topo,shortestpath);
                int paths[K][NUMBER_OF_NODES];
                initialize_two_d_array(K,NUMBER_OF_NODES,paths,-1);
                if(dist>=percentage_of(PERCENTAGE_LOWER_LIMIT,compute_optical_reach()) &&
                                        dist<=percentage_of(PERCENTAGE_UPPER_LIMIT,compute_optical_reach()))
                {
                    int paths_generated = k_shortest_path(i,j,K,
                            paths,temp_topo,compute_optical_reach());
                    if(paths_generated>=K)
                    {
                        source_destination[number_of_source_destination_generated][0] = i;
                        source_destination[number_of_source_destination_generated][1] = j;
                        number_of_source_destination_generated ++;
                    }


                }
            }
        }
    }
    if(number_of_source_destination_generated>=NUMBER_OF_SOURCE_DESTINATION)
    {
        int visited_demand[number_of_source_destination_generated];
        initialize_one_d_array(number_of_source_destination_generated,visited_demand,0);

        for (i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_SOURCE_DESTINATION; ++i)
        {
            int next_demand = random_in_range(0,number_of_source_destination_generated);
            while(visited_demand[next_demand])
                next_demand = random_in_range(0,number_of_source_destination_generated);
            visited_demand[next_demand] = 1;
            fprintf(temp_dataset,"%d\t%d\n",source_destination[next_demand][0],source_destination[next_demand][1]);
        }
    }

    else
    {
        printf("Number of Source-Destination Pairs Generated: %d\n",number_of_source_destination_generated);
        printf("Cannot generate the required number of SD pairs\nExiting...");
        exit(1);
    }


    printf("Number of Source-Destination Pairs Generated: %d\n",number_of_source_destination_generated);
    printf("Freeing up memory and flushing all buffer...\n");
    fclose(temp_dataset);
    printf("Done Generating data-sets.\n");
}
```

I realized that when I open the file, the data inside the `network_info` of type `NI` (a `struct`) gets corrupted. The `network` struct has a 2 dimensional array that represents the network. Just after opening the file, i saw garbage values been introduced in the array. The size of the `network_info` is initialized using `(NI*) malloc(sizeof(NI*))`.

Comment: Could you please post the source code?

Comment: @VincenzoMaggio i edited the question and have posted the code, thanks.

Comment: What is `K` (uppercase)? Did you mean `k` (lowercase)?

Comment: `K` is the number of shortest path between a pair of nodes i wish to find, I have left the re-factoring for later. But `k` and `K` have the same value and `K` defined as `#define`

Comment: u say double free but in your code that you show there is no free() or delete so how do u expect us to figure out if there is a double free?

Comment: @AndersK The code just crashes at `fclose`, may be the code in the background is trying to free memory address! Thanks

Comment: If you are overflowing one of your local arrays, strange things will happen.  Put the checks in to make sure you are not.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, double free or corruption errors are normally a symptom of something that is wrong much earlier in the code.  I notice that you have the following snippets of code:

```
    int number_of_source_destination_generated = 0;
    int source_destination[NUMBER_OF_SOURCE_DESTINATION][2];
```

and inside a loop:

```
source_destination[number_of_source_destination_generated][0] = i;
source_destination[number_of_source_destination_generated][1] = j;
number_of_source_destination_generated ++;
```

How are you guaranteeing that number_of_source_destination_generated is always less than NUMBER_OF_SOURCE_DESTINATION?  In particular you have later:

```
if(number_of_source_destination_generated>=NUMBER_OF_SOURCE_DESTINATION)
{
```

which is the non-error producing case.  That leads me to believe that it is expected for the lower-case variable to be bigger than the upper-case variable.  So, I believe that means you are writing to memory that is not allocated to the array you intend.  This can cause problems later, possibly the one you are asking about.  My implementation will not always complain to me if I do that, so if yours is similar, you cannot rely on the compiler to catch those errors.

I am still fairly inexperienced, so take this suggestion with a grain of skepticism (as you always should).

EDIT: I just clicked on "show more comments" and this was already being addressed.  So, nothing new here.

Comment: I thought that might be the issue, so i changed  `NUMBER_OF_SOURCE_DESTINATION` to `_BIG_SIZE` which is quite 10000 for now. By using gdb + eclipse i am looking at a very small value of `number_of_source_destination_generated`, so i guess this is not the issue any more

Comment: I was able to solve the above by changing `(NI*) malloc(sizeof(NI*)` to `(NI*) malloc(sizeof(NI)`.

Thanks for all the help guys!